# Are the following two implementations of linked list in Java same?

Tags: java, linked-list

Implementation1 ->

```
public class Node<T> {
    
    T data;
    Node<T> next; // next should point to a node which contains data of type T
    
    Node(T data){
        this.data = data;
        this.next = null;
    }
}
```

Implementation 2 ->

```
public class Node<T> {
    
    T data;
    Node<T> next; // next should point to a node which contains data of type T
    
    Node(T data){
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Since references are by default assigned null in JAVA, are the above two implementations same? I have implemented linked lists in C++ before, and am getting confused about JAVA implementation

Comment: Yes, they're the same.

Comment: @JanezKuhar Besides references, what other stuff is initialized with some value in JAVA? Can you please list them out?

Comment: See: [**JLS: 4.12.5. Initial Values of Variables**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both implementations are equal.
A stage of creation new object consists of few phases in your case (simplifying):

1. set default values on fields `data, next`, because they are references to instances of Object class then they will be `null`.
2. execution of constructor, it makes no sense to set null value in `next` field in first implementation because it is already set equaled to null by Java in the first phase.
   Also there are additional phases possible, for example, when you inherit from another class, in this case, a parent class constructor will be called before a constructor of the current class.
   Check out documentation or articles for more details (for instance - https://farenda.com/java/java-initialization-order/).